# Rectangle colouring logic

Tags: java, swing, graphics, swt

I have one three rectangles in my canvas. I wanted to change the colours of three rectangles
in a slow manner one by one.
For example: When starting the application, user should be able to see three rectangles with the same colour (blue).
After 2 secons that rectangles colour should change to red.
Again after 2 secons the next rectangles colour should get changed. 
The last one is also done the same way, that means after 2 seconds of the 2nd rectangle.

I wrote in my own way. But it is not working. All the rectanlges are changed together. I want one by one.

Could anyone give me the logic.

```
final Runnable timer = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


            //list of rectangles size =3; each contain Rectangle.
            for(int i = 0 ; i < rectangleList.size();i++){

                if(rectangleListt.get(i).getBackgroundColor().equals(ColorConstants.blue)){
                    try {

                        rectangleList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.yellow);
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //rectSubFigureList.get(i).setBorder(null);
                }/*else{
                    rectSubFigureList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.blue);
                }*/


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a Timer:

```
    // declaration: 
    static int changed = 0;

    // the timer:     
    Timer t = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Change the colour here:
                if (changed == 0) {
                  // change the first one
                } else if (changed == 1) {
                  // change the second one
                } else if (changed == 2) {
                  // change the last one
                } else {
                  ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                changed ++;

          }
     });
     t.start();
```

Comment: should I check the condition one by one manually? what will happen if I have 500 number of rectangles and I need to change the colour one by one? so this way it is not possible. Please give me some other logic..

Comment: Exactly. Also, note that I am not going to write your whole program, think a little bit yourself as well. We are just here to give you a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You're likely calling Thread.sleep inside of Swing's event thread or EDT (for event dispatch thread), and this will cause the thread itself to sleep. Since this thread is responsible for all of Swing's graphics and user interactions, this will in effect put your *entire application* to sleep, and is not what you want to have happen. Instead, read up on and use a Swing Timer for this.

References:

- [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Swing Event Dispatch Thread and Swingworker tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

To expand on Hidde's code, you could do:

```
// the timer:     
Timer t = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
     private int changed = 0; // better to keep this private and in the class
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (changed < rectangleList.size()) {
            rectangleList.setBackgroundColor(someColor);
        } else {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }
        changed++;
     }
 });
 t.start();
```

Comment: Yep, with an ArrayList is much cleaner :)